# What is the equivalent DC motor inductance for a BLDC motor is phase-to-phase inductance is known?

Tags: motor, dc, control, brushless-dc-motor, inductance

Suppose I have a 3-phase BLDC motor, and I am provided/can measure the phase-to-phase inductance. If I would like to model this BLDC motor as a standard voltage controlled DC motor, what is the relationship between the phase-to-phase inductance of the BLDC and the armature inductance of the DC?